# double redirection in login controller in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 2 types of users (simpleUser and admin) I separated them with the attribute role in the database. So I want to make double login redirect back to the attribute role.

Comment: I am unable to comprehend what you are trying to achieve. Could you be more specific with what exactly you're trying to do, where you'd want them to be redirected, etc?

Comment: in the table user i have mail , pswd etc.. and role . this role could be "client" or "admin". and i have a login view for the admin and login view for the client .. i'm asking if i can in loginController i can say  if (role=='admin') { $redirectTo="/pageadmin" } else {$redirectTo="/pageclient"}

Comment: i mean i want to make 2 possibilities of redirection in loginController testing on role

Comment: _"i'm asking if i can in loginController i can say..."_ - Have you actually _tried_ it? I mean, why ask us if you can instead of just testing it?

Comment: it didn't work .. i tried it

Comment: @NesrineMissaoui I updated my answer with a login function inside your LoginController that should help you.

Comment: it's working !! thaaaanks a lot

Comment: @NesrineMissaoui If my answer helped, I'd appreciate it if you clicked that little check mark next to it. :) Have a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoginController:

```
   public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request))) {
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password)) {
            if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
                return redirect('adminpage');
            } else {
                return redirect('clientpage');
            }
        } 
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Credentials do not match our database.'
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: should i delete it or what

Comment: If you're overriding Laravel's built in Authentication function, then you can delete it since you're redirecting the page yourself. So yes, you can delete it.

Comment: i made the  laravel system authentification

Comment: php artisan make:auth

Comment: The basic authentication scaffolding(make:auth) provides a function for logging in that uses the redirectTo. You can override the login function and redirect the user yourself, instead of using the protected attribute. I will update my answer to show for this.